# generate float random numbers

Tags: c++

I want to generate float numbers between 0 and 1, here is my code

```
    struct generate_rand
    {
        generate_rand()
        {
            srand(time(NULL));
        }
        float operator()()
        {
            return (rand()%255)/255;
        }
    }generate_f;

    std::vector<float> color(200);
    std::generate(color.begin(), color.end(), generate_f);
```

but the vector contains all ZERO, and the compiler yield a warning: 'return' : conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data. If I modify the code like this, `return rand()/255;` the result are all int type. So what the reason?

Comment: try dividing by 255.0, making it a float division rather than int.

Comment: Integer division is the first to learn in C++.

Answer (score 4):

as Naveen said, the integer arithmetics will make it an integer result.  Also, you may want to consider using

```
(float) rand() / RAND_MAX
```

to get a number from 0 to 1 with better granularity.

Comment: @Simone: You should probably test things like that before making such bold statements.

Comment: yes :) I wrote a slightly different wrong code. Is there a way to undo the vote?

Comment: i think you can click the upvote button instead and it will undo it

Comment: it tells me that my vote is locked in unless the answer is edited :-/

Answer (score 3):

Someone already answer your precise question. But maybe you would be interested by a different approach, using the boot libraries for it?

If interested, check out this link[boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) and example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main ( )  {

    uniform_real<> distribution(0, 1) ;
    mt19937 engine; 
    engine.seed(time(NULL));   
    variate_generator<mt19937, uniform_real<> > myrandom (engine, distribution);

    for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
        cout << myrandom() << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `(rand()%255)/255` performs an integer division as all its operands are integers. So the result is always 0. You should change one of them to `float`. The simplest is to use `255.0` as the divisor.

Comment: Except `255.0` is a `double`. :)

Answer (score 2):

Naveen answered correctly. Nonetheless, a better approach would be this one:

```
struct generate_rand
{
    generate_rand()
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
    }
    float operator()()
    {
        return rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
    }
} generate_f;
```

because you get "better" random values.